# How to implement JHipster security mechanism in non-spring-boot project

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, jhipster

I am trying to secure my Webapplication which is based on a Spring MVC project containing REST controllers and Angular JS pages that get all their data from these controllers.

I am not at all familiar with Spring boot, just with 'classic spring'. I'd like to use the token based authentication which JHipster creates a skeleton for.

What needs to be done to get that security part and migrate it to my current Spring project? I tried copying relevant classes and the Token generation and such works, but the SecurityConfiguration seems to do nothing (no URL's are authenticated while I do say they need to be in the config, the tokenfilter never gets called etc.)

There's possibly some structural/ configurational differences between Spring and Spring boot which cause this?

What needs to be done to get the security mechanism working in a regular Spring application?

What is working:
- token generation

What is not working:
- every REST call goes through no matter if it's behind an `.authenticated()` URL
- the token filter never checks if there's a token and thus doesn't validate the token

Everything token-wise is okay, everything url-security wise is not at all okay.

(I've been trying to solve this for 3 days now and I just don't see where I'm going wrong.)

All help/ insights/ tips much appreciated as always.

Comment: post your security config

Comment: Sorry I solved it in the meantime I'll try and update this post with an answer ASAP!

Comment: @E. V. d. B. Can you update answer please?